# T-SQL GroupBy With Summed Count Values and Group Averages based on Number Ranges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data in two tables and I am trying to generate a summary query based on ranges. The summary is designed to group based on 'GWZones' and at the same time Sum the Count Values and Display the Averages of those values based on 3 greater or less than ranges.

The range value is based on pH of water.

eg Ranges Filter1: <6.5   Filter2: >=6.5 AND < 8.5  Filter3: >=8.5

The 1st Table ('1WorksTable') contains the "GWZone" names (eg Zone1, Zone2, Zone3 (There are multiple Zones per unique 'WorksID'

```
WorksID GWZone
--------------
1       Zone1
2       Zone2
3       Zone2
4       Zone3
5       Zone3
6       Zone3
7       Zone3
```

The 2nd Table ('1phTable') contains pH values that need to be counted and their average calculated within one of three ranges (ph<7, >=7 pH <8.5, pH >=8.5)

```
LabResultsID    pH  WorksID
----------------------------
1               7       1
2               7       2
3               8       3
4               7       4
5               8       5
6               9       6
7              10       7
```

The standard T-SQL group by query results in averages for all values and ignores the three ph ranges.

The current result:

```
GWZone  SummedCountWorksID  AvgpH
----------------------------------
Zone1   1                   7
Zone2   2                   7.5
Zone3   4                   8.5
```

The required result is:

```
GWZone  SummedCountWorksID  AvgpH
----------------------------------
Zone1       1                   7
Zone2       1                   7
Zone3       1                   7
Zone2       1                   8
Zone3       1                   8
Zone3       2                   9.5
```

Partitioning may help or a case when range select within a select.

The SQL code for the tables and my basic query is;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[1WorksTable]
(
    [WorksID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GWZone] [nvarchar](15) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_1WorksTable] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WorksID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[1phTable]
(
    [LabResultsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [pH] [float] NULL,
    [WorksID] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_1Zones] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LabResultsID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[1WorksTable] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[1WorksTable] ([WorksID], [GWZone]) 
VALUES (1, N'Zone1'), (2, N'Zone2'), 
       (3, N'Zone2'), (4, N'Zone3'),
       (5, N'Zone3'), (6, N'Zone3'),
       (7, N'Zone3')
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[1WorksTable] OFF
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[1phTable] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[1phTable] ([LabResultsID], [pH], [WorksID]) 
VALUES (1, 7, 1), (2, 7, 2), (3, 8, 3),
       (4, 7, 4), (5, 8, 5), (6, 9, 6), (7, 10, 7)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[1phTable] OFF
GO
```

The failed group by query is as follows;

```
SELECT        
    dbo.[1WorksTable].GWZone, 
    COUNT(dbo.[1phTable].WorksID) AS CountWorksID, 
    AVG(dbo.[1phTable].pH) AS AvgpH
FROM
    dbo.[1WorksTable] 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.[1phTable] ON dbo.[1WorksTable].WorksID = dbo.[1phTable].WorksID
GROUP BY 
    dbo.[1WorksTable].GWZone
```

Any ideas that may help me get this query to work as needed.

Thank you for your time!

By generating the basic View with all pH data it removes the need for joins between tables that make the SQL more complex.

```
SELECT        dbo.[1WorksTable].GWZone, dbo.[1phTable].WorksID, dbo.[1phTable].pH
FROM            dbo.[1phTable] INNER JOIN
                         dbo.[1WorksTable] ON dbo.[1phTable].WorksID = dbo.[1WorksTable].WorksID
GROUP BY dbo.[1WorksTable].GWZone, dbo.[1phTable].pH, dbo.[1phTable].WorksID
```

A partial solution yields the Group Structure and as an alternative displays the ranges.

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT GWZone, pH, COUNT(WorksID) AS Observations
FROM            (SELECT        CASE WHEN pH BETWEEN 0 AND 6.5 THEN '<=6.5' WHEN pH >= 6.5 AND pH < 8.5 THEN '>=6.5 and <8.5' ELSE '>=8.5' END AS pH, WorksID, GWZone
                          FROM            dbo.ParentView) AS t
GROUP BY pH, GWZone
ORDER BY GWZone, pH
```

This yields a result like so;

```
Zone    pH Range    Sum(Count(WorksID)) 
Zone1   <6.5             1
Zone2   <6.5             1
Zone2   >=6.5 and <8.5   1
Zone3   <6.5             1
Zone3   >=6.5 and <8.5   1
Zone3   >=8.5            2
```

The only thing missing now is the calculation of averages of pH for each row.

Comment: can you explain how you get the `CountWorksID` and `AvgpH` for the expected result ?

Comment: I could not see a problem with your query. It counts the number of Works successfully and takes the average of related works without any error.

Comment: The sample data were copied from excel, minus the extra row of data;   LabResultsID GWZone pH
1 Zone1 7
2 Zone2 7
3 Zone2 8
4 Zone3 7
5 Zone3 8
6 Zone3 9
7 Zone3 10

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how you are calculating some of your figures in your required result, so I am taking a stab in the dark a little here.  I hope the following query gets you a little further along for what you are aiming in your required results.

```
SELECT      [1WorksTable].GWZone, 
            COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY [1WorksTable].GWZone ORDER BY [1phTable].WorksID) AS CountWorksID, 
            CAST(AVG([1phTable].pH) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS AvgpH
FROM        [1WorksTable] 
INNER JOIN  [1phTable] ON [1WorksTable].WorksID = [1phTable].WorksID
GROUP BY    [1WorksTable].WorksID,
            [1WorksTable].GWZone,
            [1phTable].WorksID
ORDER BY    AvgpH, 
            GWZone
```

Comment: Good Observation Ryan. The final row of data (7 Zone3 10) would have helped the math in the results.  I was aiming at the basic 1,2,3 progression of increasing pH as an easy way to observe the result showing a decimal value to identify the required difference in Zone3.   I am not sure how to format a table here.      Zone    Sum(CountWorksID)    AvgpH    "Class Range"
      Zone1 1 7 <7.5
    Zone2 1 7 <7.5
    Zone3 1 7 <7.5
    Zone1 0 0 >=7.5 AND < 8.5
    Zone2 1 8 >=7.5 AND < 8.5
    Zone3 1 8 >=7.5 AND < 8.5
    Zone1 0 0 >=8.5
    Zone2 0 0 >=8.5
    Zone3 2 9.5 >=8.5

Comment: Three of the results contain Zero values and were not listed in the original table solution example.  Your query does present the data fine Ryan, but the Zones merge based on the filter.  If the two amended values in Zone3 (9 and 10) are >=8.5 then they are averaged as Zone3 with 2 Values that averaged to 9.5.  The same math and class assignment would apply to Zones 1 and 2.  eg Zone1 had 3 individual observations of ph7 therefore the sum(count) and avg for each zone was 7.

Comment: Hi Geospatial, I have been out of town and just catching up here.  Wow, it looks like others have picked up from this point and completed the missing pieces.  This was a fun one to attempt to solve after seeing all of the results here.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to incorporate a case expression into the `partition by` of the `over() clause`

```
select *
      , CASE
            WHEN pH BETWEEN 0 AND 6.5 THEN '<=6.5'
            WHEN pH >= 6.5 AND pH < 8.5 THEN '>=6.5 and <8.5'
            ELSE '>=8.5'
        END AS ph_range
      , avg(pH) over(partition by GWZone, CASE
                        WHEN pH BETWEEN 0 AND 6.5 THEN 1
                        WHEN pH >= 6.5 AND pH < 8.5 THEN 2
                        ELSE 3 END) avg_pH
FROM [1WorksTable
INNER JOIN  [1phTable] ON [1WorksTable].WorksID = [1phTable].WorksID
ORDER BY pH, GWZone
```

This query produces (from your sample data) the following:

```
      WorksID   GWZone   LabResultsID   pH   WorksID      ph_range      avg_pH  
 --- --------- -------- -------------- ---- --------- ---------------- -------- 
  1         1   Zone1               1    7         1   >=6.5 and <8.5        7  
  2         2   Zone2               2    7         2   >=6.5 and <8.5      7.5  
  3         4   Zone3               4    7         4   >=6.5 and <8.5      7.5  
  4         3   Zone2               3    8         3   >=6.5 and <8.5      7.5  
  5         5   Zone3               5    8         5   >=6.5 and <8.5      7.5  
  6         6   Zone3               6    9         6   >=8.5               9.5  
  7         7   Zone3               7   10         7   >=8.5               9.5
```

I'm not sure how you get to the desired result exactly, but as you see above it is possible to calculate an average by the desired ranges.

also see: http://rextester.com/DRS47751